# convert the number of the calendar day to date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having 174 is there a way to convert it to show the complete date?
example: 174 should be 06/23/2014, it is the 174th day of the year. my data looks like this 2014174. is there a SQL function for this?

Thank you

Comment: i took the day out of the string, i have year on one column and day on other using substring: SUBSTRING (t1.msdatecode,2,4) and SUBSTRING (t1.msdatecode,7,3) but i need the date

Comment: Julian date is how I've heard this referred to before by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dateadd function like below, to accomplish what you are looking for.

```
declare @inputNumber int
set @inputNumber = 174
select dateadd(day,(@inputNumber-1),'1/1/'+cast (year(getdate())as varchar(10)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @DATEINT  INT
SET @DATEINT = 2014174
select DATEADD(YEAR, @DATEINT/1000-1900,DATEADD(day, @DATEINT%1000 - 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select dateadd(dd,174,dateadd(yy,year(getdate(),0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty dynamic way to do this.  It would work for variable length inputs like 201450 or 2014364 etc.

```
declare @myDate varchar(10)
declare @dayPart int
declare @yearPart int
declare @dDate datetime
set @myDate = '201459'
set @yearPart = left(@myDate,4)
set @dayPart = right(@myDate, len(@myDate)-4)

select @yearPart, @dayPart


set @dDate = '01/01/' + cast(@yearPart as varchar(4))
select @dDate
select dateadd(dd,@dayPart, @dDate)
```

Output: 03/01/2014 - The 59th day of 2014.